# Alexa unable to play audio from Firebase

Tags: firebase, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have a set of audios in my firebase, which I'm trying to play via Alexa skill.

```
<speak>
   <audio src='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aebeze-now.appspot.com/o/Moments%2Ffor-mature-audiences-only.mp3?alt=media&token=2825d8ef-5e3d-4753-b58e-0881f77f4fd3' />
</speak>
```

I tried playing above SSML in Alexa dev console 'Voice & Tone' section, but it is giving 
`Error retrieving text to speech. The input was incompatible` error.

I also tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206436/google-actions-sdk-not-playing-audio-in-ssml-from-firebase-storage) answer, but replcing "&" with "&" also didn't work.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the MP3 file format was not correct. I noticed it in the device log under "Directive: SkillDebugger.CaptureDebuggingInfo" when I tested the skill:

`"request": {
                        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
                        "requestId":
                        "timestamp": "2018-11-26T21:16:28Z",
                        "locale": "de-DE",
                        "reason": "ERROR",
                        "error": {
                            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
                            "message": "Invalid SSML Output Speech for requestId. Error: The audio is not of a supported MPEG version" 
}`

I changed the MP3 again acording to the description here and then it worked:
https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#h3_converting_mp3